# Install private Gitlab NPM package on GitlabCI globally (`npm i -g`)

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab-ci

I have made a NPM package on Gitlab registry. When I install it locally, on the consumer node project with `npm install @Ambroise-Rabier/atlas-sear-index-updater`, the CI is able to find and download the package when running `npm ci`.

However, when I try to install it globally on the runner with :

```yaml
stages:
  - test-usage

image: node:16-alpine

test-usage:
  stage: test-usage
  script:
    - npm config set @Ambroise-Rabier:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/39908186/packages/npm/ --global
    - npm config set '//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/39908186/packages/npm/:_authToken'=\${CI_JOB_TOKEN} --global
    - npm config list
    - npm i -g @Ambroise-Rabier/atlas-sear-index-updater
```

The logs:

```
$ npm i -g @Ambroise-Rabier/atlas-sear-index-updater
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@Ambroise-Rabier/atlas-sear-index-updater - Not found
```

`npm config set` is supposed to give NPM the information that it should be looking for this package in gitlab registry. But it seems like global/user `.npmrc` get ignored when installing the package globally. I have tried `--user` and `--global`.

The files in question can be found with `npm config ls -l | grep config`, it output:

```
; "default" config from default values
globalconfig = "/usr/local/etc/npmrc" 
userconfig = "/root/.npmrc"
```

I saw another post suggesting NPM could have an issue reading the `.npmrc` file, so I have tried `npm config list`, and all the values are correctly displayed.

```
; "global" config from /usr/local/etc/npmrc
@Ambroise-Rabier:registry = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/39908186/packages/npm/" 
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/39908186/packages/npm/:_authToken = (protected) 
; node bin location = /usr/local/bin/node
; node version = v16.17.1
; npm local prefix = /builds/Ambroise-Rabier/atlas-search-consumer
; npm version = 8.15.0
; cwd = /builds/Ambroise-Rabier/atlas-search-consumer
; HOME = /root
; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.
```

PS: If it was an authentication issue, it would tell me `401` or something, not `404` with this url `https://registry.npmjs.org/@Ambroise-Rabier`.
PS2: I use node 16 (and would prefer staying on node 16 for this project)

Comment: Can u cross check if you have added the token in the .npmrc file.
Also try creating .npmrc with the details at the location from where u are installing

Comment: @Origin Well, it seems it work if the package is named from A to Z with lowercase, meaning I create the package as `@ambroise-rabier` and go retrieve with `@ambroise-rabier`. Gonna make a quick response in case someone pass by with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It work by using only lowercases for the package name.

When creating the package:

```json
{
  "name": "@ambroise-rabier/atlas-search-index-updater"
}
```

```yaml
script:
  - |
    {
      echo "@ambroise-rabier:registry=${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/"
      echo "${CI_API_V4_URL#https?}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=\${CI_JOB_TOKEN}"
    } | tee -a .npmrc
    - npm version --no-commit-hooks "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
    - npm publish
```

When using it:

```yaml
script:
  - npm config set @ambroise-rabier:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/39908186/packages/npm/ --global
  - npm config set '//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/39908186/packages/npm/:_authToken'=\${CI_JOB_TOKEN} --global
  - npm i -g @ambroise-rabier/atlas-search-index-updater
  - npm list -g # <-- Log version installed
  - npx --no-install atlas-updater -h # <-- Check install
```